# Issue on custom pipe test case in angular 9?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

Here is the code of test case of custom pipe. I am trying to pass the test of custom made pipe
but it's getting failed for some reasons. Also how can i test regex in custom pipe
Also how can i test regex in custom pipe

here is [live code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-validation-r3seqd)

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'currencyWithDecimal',
})
export class CurrencyWithDecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val: string, ...args: any[]) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'INR',
      minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    }).format(Number(val));
  }
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'breakAfter',
})
export class BreakAfter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    if (value === '') {
      return '';
    }
    return value.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
  }
}
```

here is the **spec** file

```js
import { CurrencyWithDecimalPipe, BreakAfter } from  './custom.pipe'

describe('Pipes', () => {
  const currencyPipe: CurrencyWithDecimalPipe = new CurrencyWithDecimalPipe();
  const breakAfterPipe: BreakAfter = new BreakAfter();

  it('should create currencyPipe', () => {
    expect(currencyPipe).toBeTruthy();
  });

   it('should create an breakAfterPipe', () => {
    expect(breakAfterPipe).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('currency Pipe', () => {

    it('should return currency with decimal value', () => {
      expect(currencyPipe.transform('444000').toEqual('4,44,000'))
    });

  });

  describe('break after Pipe', () => {

    it('should break after br tag', () => {
      expect(breakAfterPipe.transform(`SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS error handler for form validation 
      ok lets break this.
      `).toEqual(`SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS error handler for form validation 
      ok lets break this`))
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: you arent closing the `expect()` properly. should be: `expect(currencyPipe.transform('444000')).toEqual('4,44,000')`

Comment: @Chris Thank you so much. it was silly mistake now it is fixed. :-)

Comment: @Chris can you please help me out with this. i am really stuck. the main struggle for is get into if condition and check the routes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181953/angular-9-unit-testingjasmine-karma-for-event-base-router-issue